# Unexpected payload with GetPricing and getCompetitivePricing

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

When requesting getPricing and getCompetitivePricing for certain ASINS on the US and UK marketplaces no data is returned.
With ASIN:B000092AUA on the UK marketplace, the asin exists and there are active offers.
[https://www.amazon.com/Innocence-Natural-Thing/dp/B000092AUA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000092AUA)
The returned payload for getPricing is

> {'ASIN': 'B000092AUA',
> 'Product': {'Identifiers': {'MarketplaceASIN': {'ASIN': 'B000092AUA',
> 'MarketplaceId': 'ATVPDKIKX0DER'}}},
> 'status': 'Success'}

Which is clearly missing the pricing information.
I have also tried it with getCompetitivePricing which returns an empty array for the competitive prices.
I have opened a ticket with amazon about this, does anyone know if there is a way to ensure the request returns data?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @KhorneHoly I contacted Amazon directly, they are still moving over from MWS to SP API. Apparently they are looking into it, but I wouldn't hold your breath